# Extracting HTML fields through XPath

Tags: php, dom, xpath, simplexml

I have this query which extracts the posts which has been "liked" more than 5 times.

```
//div[@class="pin"]
[.//span[@class = "LikesCount"]
[substring-before(normalize-space(text())," ") > 5]
```

I'd like to extract and store additional informations like titles,img url,like number,repin number,...

**How to extract them all ?**

- Multiple XPath queries?
- Digging into the nodes of the resulted posts while iterating with php and php functions?
- ...

Follows a Markup example:

```
<div class="pin">

<p class="description">gorgeous couch <a href="#">#modern</a></p>

[...]

<div class="PinHolder">
<a href="/pin/56787645270909880/" class="PinImage ImgLink">
    <img src="http://media-cache-ec3.pinterest.com/upload/56787645270909880_d7AaHYHA_b.jpg" 
         alt="Krizia" 
         data-componenttype="MODAL_PIN" 
         class="PinImageImg" 
         style="height: 288px;">
</a>
</div>

<p class="stats colorless">
    <span class="LikesCount"> 
        22 likes 
    </span>
    <span class="RepinsCount">
        6 repins
    </span>
</p>

[...]

</div>
```

Comment: What does the 'best' way mean for you?

Comment: Once I got the right posts, I don't know which is the best approach to extract store and organize all those informations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are already using XPath in your code I would suggest to extract that information using XPath too. Here comes an example on how to extract the description.

```
<?php 

// will store the posts as assoc arrays
$mostLikedPostsArr = array();

// call your fictional load function
$doc = load_html('whatever');

// create a XPath selector
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

// this your query from above
$query = '//div[@class="pin"][.//span[@class = "LikesCount"][substring-before(normalize-space(text())," ") > 5]';

// getting the most liked posts
$mostLikedPosts = $selector->query($query);

// now iterate through the post nodes
foreach($mostLikedPosts as $post) {

    // assoc array for a post
    $postArr = array();

    // you can do 'relative' queries once having a reference to $post
    // note $post as the second parameter to $selector->query()

    // lets extract the description for example
    $result = $selector->query('p[@class = "description"]', $post);
    // just using nodeValue might be ok for text only nodes.
    // to properly flatten the <a> tags inside the descriptions 
    // it will take further attention.
    $postArr['description'] = $result->item(0)->nodeValue;

    // ...

    $mostLikedPostsArr []= $postArr;
}
```

Comment: looks cool!! But I don't get how you extract the description that way: where is $node defined? And why don't you assign the query result?

Comment: Sorry didn't tried to code. Of course $node wasn't defined. ;) Updated it.

Comment: Note that you should not use $result->item(0) without checking $result->length before. Just wanted to keep the example as simple as possible.

Comment: interesting, I put an echo instead of the array assignment. But it just shows always the same description. Looks like that the 'relative' query is not relative at all. wierd

Comment: my fault - my query was //p[@class="description".  But if the query is 'relative' shouldn't work anyway as the 'root' should be just the post and not the whole document

Comment: Yes, without `//` queries will be resolved from the $post node. When using `//` the documents root is the starting point. Look at the manual of [DOMXPath::query](http://php.net/manual/de/domxpath.query.php). The param is called `contextnode`.